# Add an OR to IF condition

Tags: excel

I am trying to add a new condition to my formula below:

> =IF(E2="Resolved";IF(AND(E3="New";I2=I3);"Yes";IF(AND(E4="New";I4=I2);"Yes";"No"));"")

Basically this formula will compare values of column I if the column E has the word "Resolved". What I will need is to add a new word to look for besides the "Resolved". So the comparison will work if "Resolved" or "Dismissed" words are found. If not, doesnt do nothing.

Tried to use OR but always getting error.

Print below with more details.

[image]

Comment: `OR` should work. Did you try `=IF(OR(E2="Resolved";E2="Dismissed");...`?

Comment: ... *or* `=IF(OR(E2={"Resolved";"Dismissed"});...` This works with hard-coded constants; it does not work with multiple cell addresses.

Answer (score 4):

The `OR` function will work as such `=IF(OR(E1="Resolved",E1="Dismissed"),DOSOMETHING,"")`. 
If column E is either Resolved or Dismissed then the `OR` returns true and the `IF` will perform the `DOSOMETHING`. If column E is neither Resolved or Dismissed it will do nothing.